# Removing JQuery/Javascript keyboard hooks (e.g. Portfolio Slide Gallery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm implementing the Portfolio slide gallery in my web site (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/09/portfolio-image-navigation/) and it contains keyboard event handlers for image navigation. If you check out the link, he describes the init.js file, but the download also contains portfolio.js, css files and a demo html.

Unfortunately, where I AJAX to refresh the content pane, the keyboard handlers remain. Any keyboard presses are blocked until the page completely refreshes.

I'm not sure what to do, but have a few ideas which I may not have implemented proplerly.

1. I'd like to try ending the 'js process' for want of a better term,
   which may have something to do with a call related to the code in
   init.js;
2. I've already tried setting the bundled gallery js file
   function, which appears to handle handlers to null;
3. I've tried
   various jQuery handler unbinders, which throw a "... is not a
   function". the handlers don't appear to be inside the portfolio.js
   either;
4. I don't currently use the keyboard anywhere else, so perhaps
   a global keyboard handler unbinder function would solve it.

Any help here would be great, I'll add code as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the following from portfolio.js should do the trick, it's the only bind I could find in the example on codrops. (Edit: Downloaded the demo's source and tried, confirming that removing the following bind works.)

```
                        $(document).bind(type, function(e) {
                            var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
                            if(code == key && $(element).is(':visible')) { 
                                if (!inside.is(':animated')) {
                                    inside.animate(object, s.animationSpeed, function(){
                                        plugin.position.get(inside);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        });
```

Comment: Oh, you saint! Perhaps one day, I'll be able to figure things out that quick!